# how to get value in Editor in mvc5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get value in the editor but undefined incoming?

```
 @Html.Editor("ProductName")
```

Javascript code...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".click").click(function () {
         var proName = $("ProductName").val();

         var code = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name = 'chk'/></td><td>" + proName +"</td></tr>"

    }
}
```

Comment: Try add # before ProductName => var propName = $("#ProductName").val();

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, if you want to select an element by its Id then you should specify # sign before Id.

```
var proName = $("#ProductName").val();
```

For more information please follow [this.](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)